# WPFToolkit charts in Itemscontrol

Tags: charts, wpftoolkit, itemscontrol, lineseries

OK here is what I'm trying to do. I need multiple list charts in a single chart control. No problem that's easy enough using Sheog's answer on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10604545/1836291

The problem is that I don't know how many charts i need until run-time. So my idea is to put it into an items control and set the data template as a LineSeries like so:

```
                       <ItemsControl x:Name="pieChart">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <chartingToolkit:Chart DataContext="{Binding}"  Title="Pie Series Demo" Margin="0" Background="#FF48474B" Height="400"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
```

And my data:

```
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 60));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 20));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 50));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 30));
        valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 40));


        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> valueList2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        valueList2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Developer", 40));
        valueList2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Misc", 40));
        valueList2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Tester", 40));
        valueList2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("QA", 40));
        valueList2.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Project Manager", 20));

        var dataSourceList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>>();
        dataSourceList.Add(valueList);
        dataSourceList.Add(valueList2);

        pieChart.DataContext = dataSourceList;
```

My feeling is that the problem lies somewhere in my databinding but, I don't know enough about it to troubleshoot it.

Well I found this:

[Programmatically create a ColumnSeries WPF Toolkit Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926036/programmatically-create-a-columnseries-wpf-toolkit-charts)

and it does in fact work quite nicely but, i'd still like to know how to do this in XAML.

Thank you,